# Setting file.encoding to invalid charset using java opts

Tags: java, character-encoding

I've the following class:

```
public class PrintCharSet{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("System Props (file.encoding): " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
        System.out.println("Default Charset: " + java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());
    }
}
```

When I run on My Linux box I got:

```
$ java PrintCharSet
System Props (file.encoding): UTF-8
Default Charset: UTF-8
```

And When I specify a valid charset via file.encoding prop to JVM like this, it works:

```
$ java -Dfile.encoding=WINDOWS-1256 PrintCharSet 
System Props (file.encoding): WINDOWS-1256
Default Charset: windows-1256
```

But the question is, When I use invalid charset name, why I not got some initialization error instead of using the default one (as if I provide empty value for file.encoding props to indicate a problem in initialization phase)

```
$ java -Dfile.encoding=INALID_CHARSET_NAME PrintCharSet 
System Props (file.encoding): INALID_CHARSET_NAME
Default Charset: UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not well defined and sun/oracle considers it an internal implementation detail. According to sun/oracle, "The preferred way to change the default encoding used by the VM and the runtime system is to change the locale of the underlying platform before starting your Java program."

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4163515